# DesktopImageInSystemMemory of DXGI_OUTDUPL_DESC

Tags: c++, windows, screen-scraping, directx-11

I need this variable to be TRUE so that I can use MapDesktopSurface of IDXGIOutputDuplication

How do we set this to true. What previous settings can be done.

Here is a link

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404622(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404622%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: *...the application must first transfer the image to a staging surface and then lock the image by calling the [IDXGISurface::Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174567(v=vs.85).aspx) method...*

Comment: Ok thats what i was worried about. I was trying to skip that stage if creating a temp surface.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem...So this is what you need to do:

The **MapDesktopSurface** method will most of the times return **DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED** as the image is not in the system memory, but in GPU memory.

In this case, you need to transfer that image from **GPU memory to System memory**.

So how to do that?

1. Create a descriptor for `ID3D11Texture2D` of type `D3D11_TEXTURE12D_DESC`.
2. Use `GetDesc` on the image(`ID3D11Texture2D`) that you acquired using `IDXGIOutputDuplication::AcquireNextFrame` to fill in the descriptor.
3. This descriptor that you get has `frameDescriptor.Usage` set to `D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT`.
4. You need to set the descriptor with following parameters (let others remain as it is):

   ```
   frameDescriptor.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
   frameDescriptor.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
   frameDescriptor.BindFlags = 0;
   frameDescriptor.MiscFlags = 0;
   frameDescriptor.MipLevels = 1;
   frameDescriptor.ArraySize = 1;
   frameDescriptor.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
   ```
5. Now, create a new **staging buffer** (`ID3D11Texture2D`) using the above descriptor as follows:

   ```
   m_Device->CreateTexture2D(&frameDescriptor, NULL, &newId3d11Texture2D);
   ```
6. Copy the contents of the acquired image to your **staging buffer** as follows:

   ```
   m_DeviceContext->CopyResource(newId3d11Texture2D, m_AcquiredDesktopImage);
   ```
7. **Important:** Release the acquired frame using `IDXGIOutputDuplication::ReleaseFrame()`
8. Now you can process this newTexture (`newId3d11Texture2D`) as you wish!!!!!

Map it if you want...

This should be enough for answering your query...if you want more information, you can always check out the msdn pages or ask through comments...